# Beamer : "bclogo" box with title only?

Tags: beamer, bclogo

Although I'm afraid what I'm looking for is not (yet !) possible, I'll ask it : is there a way, with the "bclogo" package within a Beamer document to create a box showing a logo + the box title but no contents (and no space reserved for contents).

Here's my code :

```
\begin{bclogo}[epBord=0.1, arrondi=0.4,
    couleur=white, logo=\bcplume,
    ombre=true, couleurOmbre=gray!50, epOmbre=0.1, blur,
    barre=none
    ]{the title}
\end{bclogo}
```

This displays a nice beautiful box (as expected) showing the logo + title in the upper half of the box, and a blank space in the bottom half.

It is possible to instruct "bclogo" that there is no content and no need to reserve white space for it ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I found only a French version of the package documentation, but if I understood it correctly, one could modify the margins to fit the text. Of course this is a non-automatic solutions which would have to be adapted depending on the content of the box.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{bclogo}[epBord=0.1, arrondi=0.4,
    couleur=white, logo=\bcplume,
    ombre=true, couleurOmbre=gray!50, epOmbre=0.1, blur,
    barre=none, margeG=4, margeD=4
    ]{the title}
\end{bclogo}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Automatic Solution** (but not using `bclogo`)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins} 

\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \tcbset{enhanced,colframe=black,colback=white,colupper=black, fonttitle=\bfseries,center title,size=title,arc=4mm,frame style={drop shadow},boxrule=0.1mm}
    \centering
    \tcbox{\raisebox{-.25\height}{\bcplume}Title}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]